# How to respond to professor about visa problems when applying for a post-doc?

Tags: application, united-states, postdocs, visa, china

Currently I'm in the process of my post-doc application in the US, but I may encounter some inevitable problems with my visa (J-1) application. The professor said that they have not had any scientists from China for a long time and some of the people they invited never got visas.

How should I tell my professor that I'm willing to apply for my visa despite the possibility of getting declined? Or, should I do nothing and wait to see if it changes?

Comment: To clarify, you haven't actually had any problems yet? If that's the case, I don't think you need to do anything...

Comment: You should see if the university has an office that helps deal with visa issues.

Comment: To all who know more that I do about visas: Is it possible to get a J-1 visa without already having an offer?

Comment: @Buffy I believe J-1 applications require a sponsoring institution (at least in the research scholar category), so probably having an offer would be needed.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. The J-1 visa requires the DS2019 form, which I did not acquire from the University Department. 
Tell the professor that I will try to apply for a visa, even though the professor said that he wanted to wait for the situation to change. Is it impolite to do so?